# How to send different message to multiple users by hitting single api of FCM?

Tags: node.js, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a use case where I want to send a notification using FCM to multiple users(say 1000) every minute.
Below are some conditions that I also need to take care of

- Every minute users will be different based on some conditions. So i can't create a group or topic using fcm.
- Every user will receive a different message.
- I don't want to hit fcm's request 1000 times every single minute.

Please help here

Answer (score 0):

You can [send a batch of (up to 500) messages](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send-a-batch-of-messages), where each message has its own payload and audience (such a topic of tokens). So for 1000 unique tokens, you'd in that case only hit the API endpoint twice.

The Admin SDK (which is available for Node.js) implement a simple method call for this, but I also recommend having a look at the REST API example on the page I linked, as I found it interesting to see how this is implemented behind the scenes.